# Azure ACS with Silverlight website

Tags: silverlight, azure, acs

I'm new with Windows Azure and Silverlight. I'm trying to do a simple silverlight website with an authentication using Windows Live ID. So far, I managed to make it work easily using a simple ASP.net WebRole (lots of tuto about it) but not with Silverlight.
For my Silverlight site, I created a WCFServiceWebRole with the Silverlight xap referenced. It works fine, and now I need to authenticate the user and get the claims.
To put it simply, I need to do just like the Azure website (you use your Live ID and then you access the Silverlight Portal).

How could I do that ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Silverlight business applications / WCF RIA services you want to drive signin using the browser WS-FEDERATION signin process at which point the required WS-FEDERATION session token cookies will automatically be included in all RIA services requests.

The WIF Identity Developer Training Kit does include samples showing how to use WS-TRUST active profile signin in Silverlight clients but for WCF RIA services and the corresponding Silverlight business application client UI this will make things harder.

Until you have more specific questions, please look at the training kit.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14347

Comment: Thanks ! I found what I was looking for in this training kit ! I had the training kit for Azure only.
I just had to do the same as the WIF exemple and then use the FederationMetadata.xml from my Azure account instead of the one provided.
Thanks again.